Dependent question with a lot of values in shinysurveys
I am making a Shinysurvey for some government agency. I have a dummy questionary.
This are the questions dataframe head



question
option
input_type
input_id
dependence
dependence_value
required




Nombre completo del personal que captura.
Nombre Primer apellido Segundo apellido
text
nombre_personal
NA
NA
TRUE


Cargo
De acuerdo al organigrama
text
cargo
NA
NA
TRUE


Correo electrónico
En minúsculas
text
correo
NA
NA
TRUE


Entidad federativa
BAJA CALIFORNIA
select
entidad
NA
NA
TRUE


Entidad federativa
BAJA CALIFORNIA SUR
select
entidad
NA
NA
TRUE


Entidad federativa
CAMPECHE
select
entidad
NA
NA
TRUE



Tail



question
option
input_type
input_id
dependence
dependence_value
required




CODE
AAAAA055555
select
code
entidad
ZACATECAS
TRUE


CODE
AAAAA055556
select
code
entidad
ZACATECAS
TRUE


¿Cuenta con energía eléctrica?
Sí
y/n
luz
NA
NA
TRUE


¿Cuenta con energía eléctrica?
No
y/n
luz
NA
NA
TRUE


¿Cuenta con internet?
Sí
y/n
internet
NA
NA
TRUE


¿Cuenta con internet?
No
y/n
internet
NA
NA
TRUE



This is the code I'm using. And it works.
library(shiny)
library(shinysurveys)

df <- read.csv("cuestionario_previa.csv", encoding = "latin1")
ui <- fluidPage(
  surveyOutput(df = df,
               survey_title = "Servicios de Energia Electrica e Internet",
               survey_description = "Cuestionario rápido para el diagnostico de los servicios de luz e internet)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  renderSurvey()
  
  observeEvent(input$submit, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      title = "Congrats, you completed your first shinysurvey!",
      "You can customize what actions happen when a user finishes a survey using input$submit."
    ))
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

But, as you can see in the tail, I have a question called CODE which is a dependent one from the question "entidad".
i.e. If entidad == "COLIMA" I want a subset of CODE for this state.
With my dataframe I get this warning:
Warning message:
The select input "code" contains a large number of options; consider using server-side selectize for massively improved performance. See the Details section of the ?selectizeInput help topic.
I tried the ideas from: Is there any other way to create dependent survey questionnaire using R Shiny?
but couldn´t make it work
Also, I tried adding the selectize to my server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  renderSurvey()
  
  updateSelectizeInput(session, "clues")
  
  observeEvent(input$submit, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      title = "Congrats, you completed your first shinysurvey!",
      "You can customize what actions happen when a user finishes a survey using input$submit."
    ))
    
  })
}


the use of updateSelectizeInput seems to be wrong. It should be something like:
  updateSelectizeInput(session, 'id', choices = options, selected = character(0), server = TRUE)

where session is the session refering object, options is an character var with the full list of options to show, selected can be character(0) to show no default option or char string, and server = TRUE, that enables server side selectize.
I dont know how works the shinysurvey package, but you could develop the survey from scratch using nav_panel_hidden and working out the logic observing the answers.
